# LinqPad and Newtonsoft.Json 6.0

Tags: .net, reference, json.net, linqpad

After upgrading to Newtonsoft.JSON 6.0, whenever i reference my assemblies in LinqPad, i'm getting the following error:

Assembly 'Serenity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Serenity.Core is my assembly that has a reference to Newtonsoft.JSON 6.0. There are no other assembly in query that references version 4.5. I'm suspecting Linqpad has an internal reference to 4.5 (using ILSpy, i found that it has an internal assembly named Linqpad.Newtonsoft.Json).

Tried adding bindRedirect to LinqPad.exe.config with no luck.

How can i solve this?

Comment: For those who may experience same issue, there was a Json.Net assembly left in Plugins folder. Probably added it there, and forgot. Just remove it.